# Codeigniter model empty query

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is the model

```
<?php
Class Clase_model extends CI_Model
{
  function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function getAll(){
    $query = $this-> db ->get("clase");
    if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
       {
         return $query->result();
       }
       else
       {
         return false;
       }
  }


}
?>
```

and this is the controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Clase extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('clase_model','',TRUE);
 }

 function index()
 {
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
        $data['clases'] = $this->clase_model->getAll();
        //$this->load->view('header', $data);
        //$this->load->view('clase_view', $data);
        print_r ($data['clases']);

     }
     else{

          redirect('login', 'refresh');
     }
 }

}
?>
```

The connexion with the database is correct because another model is working correct ,but in this when I try to print the result of the query it's empty but the table it's not empty,it's something wrong??

Comment: change your condition to if($query -> num_rows() >0)

Comment: dont know about codeigniter, is it case sensitive? weather $query = $this-> db ->get("clase"); has to be wriiten as $query = $this-> db ->get("Clase"); im not confirm about this

Comment: The name of the table its clase

Comment: you should change  if($query -> num_rows() == 1) to if($query -> num_rows() >= 1) because result sometime return be more than one record. so num_rows() function can have more than one record as well.

Comment: @saty has it right. If there's more than one row in the table it's going to go to the else statement. Use `if($query->num_rows() > 0)`.

Comment: what is empty?$data['clases']? I think you getting `false` value as you are returning `false` from your model.You getting right value as your code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
<?php
Class Clase_model extends CI_Model
{
  function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function getAll(){
    $query = $this-> db ->get("clase");
    if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
       {
         return $query->result_array();
       }
       else
       {
         return false;
       }
  }


}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

your model is working for me... i think it's not load properly at your end.

can you try this:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class Clase extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
 parent::__construct();
 $this->load->model('clase_model');
}

function index()
{
if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
    $data['clases'] = $this->clase_model->getAll();
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    print_r ($data['clases']);
 }
 else{

      redirect('login', 'refresh');
 }
}

}
?>
```